# DigitCount[], but in negative bases

Tags: binary, digits, number-bases

The `DigitCount[n,b]` function "counts the gives a list of the numbers of $1, 2, \ldots, b-1, 0$ digits in the base-$b$ representation of $n$".

I want to extend this to negative bases, for instance when $b=-2$. Is there already a function for this is Mathematica? Or perhaps a "quick" solution?

## Question

**How to extend `DigitCount[n,b]` for negative `b`?**

## Due diligence

Wikipedia's [Negative base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base) article provides [code examples to calculate negative base representation in various languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base#Example_implementation_code), but no *Wolfram Language*.

[`BaseForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseForm.html), [`IntegerDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html) and [`IntegerLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerLength.html) explicitly state in their error messages that the bases must be integers larger than $1$, so it seems that current versions of Mathematica do not have built-in implementations for negative basis.

```
BaseForm[42, -2]
```

> **BaseForm::intpm**: Positive machine-sized integer expected at position 2 in `BaseForm[42, -2]`

```
IntegerDigits[42, -2]
```

> **IntegerDigits::ibase**: Base -2 is not an integer greater than 1.

```
IntegerLength[42, -2]
```

> **IntegerLength::ibase**: Base -2 is not an integer greater than 1.

Comment: In the future, probably you could do a minimum due diligence research yourself, and share how far you managed to go. The code was readily available from a quick search.

Comment: It would be reasonable to request Wolfram Development team (via Wolfram Support) to include support for negative bases in future versions.

Comment: I think this would be a great feature and to avoid the the diffusion of responsibility I have submitted a request to Wolfram to include this in future upgrades :)

Comment: I have updated my previously mistaken answer, I think now I got it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Background

[**mathworld.wolfram.com**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Base.html) contains entries for [Negabinary](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Negabinary.html), [Negadecimal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Negadecimal.html) and [Base](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Base.html), including *Wolfram language* code examples

#### Base $(-2)$ `Negabinary`

```
Negabinary[n_Integer] := Module[
    {t = (2/3)(4^Floor[Log[4, Abs[n] + 1] + 2] - 1)},
    IntegerDigits[BitXor[n + t, t], 2]
]
```

#### Base $(-10)$ `Negadecimal`

```
Negadecimal[0] := {0}
Negadecimal[i_] := Rest @ Reverse @ Mod[
     NestWhileList[
           (# - Mod[#, 10])/-10&,
           i, 
           # != 0& 
     ], 10]
```

#### In general, `NegativeIntegerDigits`

```
NegativeIntegerDigits[0, n_Integer?Negative] := {0}
NegativeIntegerDigits[i_, n_Integer?Negative] :=    Rest @ Reverse @ Mod[
    NestWhileList[
    (# - Mod[#, -n])/n& ,
    i,
    # != 0& 
    ],    -n
    ]
```

## Now this should be the right answer

Now that you can calculate the digits, you can easily measure the [`Count`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html) the digits

```
 Map[ Count[NegativeIntegerDigits[n, b],#]&, Mod[Range[Abs[b]],Abs[b]] ]
```

### Solution

We can [`Unprotect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect.html) the definition of [`DigitCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DigitCount.html), extend its definition for negative bases, [`RotateRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateRight.html) the evaluation order (to put our definition first and avoid parameter checks that triggers ["DigitCount::base"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/DigitCount/base.html) [`Message`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html)) and then [`Protect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protect.html) again. I use the definition of `NegativeIntegerDigits` from [mathworld.wolfram.com](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Base.html).

```
NegativeIntegerDigits[0, n_Integer?Negative] := {0}
NegativeIntegerDigits[i_, n_Integer?Negative] := Rest @ Reverse @ Mod[ NestWhileList[ (# - Mod[#, -n])/n& , i, # != 0&  ], -n ];

(* Unprotect the definition of DigitCount *)
Unprotect[DigitCount];
(* Our new definition for negative bases *)
DigitCount[n_Integer, b_Integer /; b < -1] := Map[Count[NegativeIntegerDigits[n, b],#]&,Mod[Range[Abs[b]],Abs[b]] ];
(* Change the evaluation order. Moves the new definition from last to first positions. *)
(* This is to skip a parameter check that triggers the 'DigitCount::base'  Message *)
DownValues[DigitCount] = RotateRight[DownValues[DigitCount]];
(* Protect again *)
Protect[DigitCount];
```

And now

```
DigitCount[18,-10]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice use of `NestWhileList` +1

Comment: which parameter check are you referring to?

Comment: This would be a long explanation, I may craft a question about this, but in short, the internal definition of `DigitCount` includes `DigitCount[pattern] := digitcountcore[args] /; TestDCArgs[args];`  I mean that `/; TestDCArgs` that give errors if the base is negative.

Comment: Updated with a better solution to avid the parameter check that triggers  "DigitCount::base" `Message`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution which uses a loop format mimicking the solutions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base)

```
integerDigits[0, n_Integer?Negative] := {0};
integerDigits[number_Integer, base_Integer?Negative]:=
  With[
   {absBase = Abs[base]},
   Module[
    {quotient = number, remainder, remainders},
    remainders =
     Reap@While[
       quotient != 0,
       {quotient, remainder} = QuotientRemainder[quotient, base];
       If[
        Negative[remainder], {quotient, remainder} += {1, absBase}];
       Sow[remainder];
       ];
    Reverse@First@remainders[[2]]
    ]
   ];


digitCount[n_Integer, b_Integer?Negative] := 
  Count[integerDigits[n, b], #] & /@ Range[Abs[b]];

digitCount[n_Integer] := digitCount[n, -10]

digitCount[n_Integer, b_Integer?Negative, d_Integer?Positive] := 
  Count[integerDigits[n, b], d];
```

So

```
integerDigits[18, -10]
digitCount[18, -10]
```

> {1, 9, 8}

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}

Comment: +1, but I think the original `DigitCount` has the counts for zero at the end of the list. *i.e* `DigitCount[199000,10]` gives `{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3} ` not `{3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2} `.

Comment: Good point, I have just noticed that too. I will edit my answer